# Merge Algorithm View read only

Tags: sql-view, mysql-5.6

The following is my view:

```
select 
    `u`.`last_name` AS `last_name`,
    `u`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
    `u`.`user_eid` AS `user_eid`,
    `um`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
    `u`.`user_id_req` AS `user_id_req`
from
    (`user` `u`
    left join `user_eid_user_id_map` `um` ON ((`u`.`user_eid` = `um`.`user_eid`)))
```

There are no functions or clauses that would cause this to use a temp table but it returns as read only. Can anyone point out the reason as to why and what I can do to make it able to update the underlying tables?

I think the reason might be the `left join`, but that is not on the list depicted in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html

*Some views are updatable. That is, you can use them in statements such as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT to update the contents of the underlying table. For a view to be updatable, there must be a one-to-one relationship between the rows in the view and the rows in the underlying table. There are also certain other constructs that make a view nonupdatable.*

Comment: Thank you, I missed that section some how.